# How do coordinates of points transform when looking from a different plane?

Tags: geometry

I have a X-Y plane with 4 dots, one on the origin, two on the x and y axis and the the fourth on in the first quadrant (corners of a rectangle). I know the coordinates of these dots. If I see these dots through another angle, the plane will change and the distance the projection of these dots on the new plane will change too.. I want to learn how to calculate the new coordinates of these dots. What I have is the angle line perpendicular to the new plane. Angle which it makes with XY Plane and YZ Plane.

[image]

Above is the image of points on X-Y Plane

[image]

Same thing viewed from a different plane. In this specific case, the line perpendicular to the plane is making 20 degrees with XY plane and 60 degrees with YZ plane. XY Plane is not at the bottom of each stand, but passes through the center of each octagonal surface.

This seems as simple cos and sin of straight lines but I just cannot imagine/visualize it. Please refer the images. The images have dishes and the point I'm talking about are their centers. The numbers in the images came from CAD software, But I'd like to know how to find them manually.

This question is somewhat of a followup of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3228123/in-a-field-of-3x3-solar-dishes-that-can-track-the-position-of-the-sun-how-to-ca) a few weeks ago. I have thought of a way to solve my problem, but will require help studying coordinate system.

Thanks.

Comment: First you need to decide what sort of a projection describes the view. An orthogonal projection is going to produce rather different results than a perspective projection, for instance.

Comment: @amd These surfaces are going to be seen by sun, and as it is from very far away, I'm gonna go with orthogonal projection.